# Creating index while updating the documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection I am updating adding a new field.
The document looks like:

```
{"A": "P145", "B":"adf", "C":[{"df":"14", "color":"blue"},{"df":17}], 
     "_id":ObjectID(....), "Synonyms":{"Synonym1": "value1", 
          "Synonym2": ["value1", "value2"]}}
```

In the update I am adding new elements to C

I want to create a index on the field A and B. A and B are 20206 unique fields. The queries to the database will be based on these fields.
The "_id" is set by default.

I plan to do it with `collection.ensure_index({"A":1, "B":1}, background=True)`

How much time could it need? It will be faster than the system index based on "_id"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of time it takes to add the index would depend on your hardware, but with 20206 records a simple index as you describe shouldn't take very long for most hardware.

Queries fully covered by the index (i.e. where you specify A and B, or just A, but **not** just B - indexes cover from left to right so unless you include A in the select, the index can't be used) will be much faster to retrieve the results. Unless you are searching by _id, the default index on _id won't help you at all; queries on A and B will have to perform a full collection scan without your proposed index, which is orders of magnitude slower than an index scan.

Inserts will be slightly slower as the index will need to be updated too, but again with a relatively small number of total documents, this isn't likely be a large overhead.

The updates to change the C collection may well be faster if you are using A and B to identify which document to update, as they will benefit from the faster search, and the update should not be impacted once the data is found as the index should not need changing.

As the absolute performance will be specific to your hardware, if you're concerned about it the best thing to do is try it out on a copy of the data (on similar hardware) and measure whether the performance meets your needs. The [output from explaining the query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/) can be very informative in understanding how your indexes are impacting your query performance.

Comment: I don't plan to insert new documents to the collection I'll add more fields. But I might end up doing two indexes one for each field. Thanks

Comment: @Llopis Whether to do one or two indexes depends on your access pattern - if you're always going to be querying by both A and B, then the single index is perfect, if you're doing a mix of the two then two indexes might be better for some queries, but slower for when you're querying on both A and B. You can always do two indexes - A and B, and just B, this will cover queries with both A and B, and queries with either A or B (as just A gets covered by A + B, no need to explicitly index A).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the time taken to create the index totally depends on the hardware (system) you are using and the number of records. for ~20K records it should be quick and not take more time. max few seconds in worst case. Little off topic, but i see that you have given background true option, probably its not needed as these background options are used while create a very large data set.Please consider few things while creating index, not only for this question but in general.

1. when you create Index in **foreground** they block the operation and wouldn't allow the read operation and that the reason background true is used. http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/indexes/
2. the good part with foreground index creation is that the indexes are more compact and better compare to background. hence it should be preferred.
3. The good news is over a long run, both background index creation and foreground delivers the same performance and does'nt matter which way the indexes were created. ... Happy Mongoing.. ;-)

-$

Comment: The point number 1 is the main reason I use the background, I am updating it at the moment. Could you provide some reference about point 2? Edit: I should note I already marked an answer as accepted

Comment: sure Liopis, let me see where I had got that information. though I read from few sources but not recalling it right now where I read that...give me sometime, i am positive that i can find the source.

Comment: [link] (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets)

You can find the below content where they mentioned that building in background results in "less compact index structure" [compare to foreground].
"Building the index on the background, takes longer than the foreground index build and results in a less compact index structure. Additionally, the background index build may impact write performance on the primary. However, building the index in the background allows the set to be continuously up for write operations while MongoDB builds the index"

Comment: Thanks but that link refers to a Replica set, and I don't have that configuration